# Is there a default String conversion method in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

Is there a default method that gets called when I try to cast an object into a string?  (E.g. toString in Java or __str__ in Python.)  I want to be able to do the following with an array of Objects, but some of them might be nil:

```
for item in array {
    writeln(item : string);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, casting nil to string isn't necessarily a problem:

```
class C {
  var x:int;
}

var array = [ new C(1), nil:C, new C(2) ];

for item in array {
  writeln( item : string ); 
}
```

outputs

```
{x = 1}
nil
{x = 2}
```

Secondly, if you did want to customize the output of your class C, you'd write a writeThis method (or a readWriteThis method). See [The readThis(), writeThis(), and readWriteThis() Methods](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelIO.html#the-readthis-writethis-and-readwritethis-methods). The writeThis method will be called both for cast to string and also for normal I/O. For example:

```
class C {
  var x:int;
  proc writeThis(writer) {
    writer.writef("{%010i}", x);
  }
}

var array = [ new C(1), nil:C, new C(2) ];

for item in array {
  writeln( "writing item : string  ", item : string ); 
  writeln( "writing item           ", item);
}
```

outputs

```
writing item : string  {0000000001}
writing item           {0000000001}
writing item : string  nil
writing item           nil
writing item : string  {0000000002}
writing item           {0000000002}
```

There is more I could say about why it works this way, what it might do in the future, and the limitations of the current strategy... but a mailing list would be a better place for such discussion if you'd like to have it.